# CSS　高さを変更せずに画像を拡大

Tags: css

ライン企業サイトのNEWSのように
画像の高さを変更しないまま画像を拡大する方法を
ご存知の方がいらっしゃったらご教授お願いします。
ブラウザの幅が800px以下になると現れます。
http://linecorp.com/ja/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

リンク先のサイトはスライドショーになっているのでJavaScript側で制御しているのだと思います。適当なライブラリを探してみてください。

また静的に画像を1枚表示すればよいのであれば[background-size:cover](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)で実現できます。ただし縦横比によって動作が変わりますので、上のサイトのように横幅によってレイアウトを切り替える必要があります。

Comment: スライドショーの下に表示されているNEWSのバナーのことを指しているのだと思います。

Comment: @unarist ご指摘ありがとうございます。coverではなくcontainですね。

Comment: ありがとうございます！coverで解決する事が出来ました